# How to show bar graphs one by one in android?

Tags: android, bar-chart

Right now i have created a bar-chart in android using AchartEngine library.

Here my problem is,

After getting launch of the emulator, my application is showing the bar-charts instantly,
But my need is to show each bar one by one.Which means each bars should want to be visible one after another.

How to do this?

Suggestions please?

*Please find my sources for reference*

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn_result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn_result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1_invoke);
    btn_result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intnt = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result_BarActivity.class);
            startActivity(intnt);

        }
    });    }}
```

**Result_BarActivity.java**

```
public class Result_BarActivity extends Activity 
{
RelativeLayout rltv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_barchart);

    final GraphicalView grfv =createIntent();  

    RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_ID);
    rl.addView(grfv);
   }

 public GraphicalView createIntent() 
 {

  rltv = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_ID);  

  String[] titles = new String[] { "Order's profit of the year", " " };

  List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

  values.add(new double[] { 7, 2, 5, 8 });
  values.add(new double[] {});

  int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE};

  XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
  renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

  setChartSettings(renderer, "Profit for the year 2012", " ", " ",0,10, 0,10, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

  renderer.setXLabels(1);
      renderer.addXTextLabel(0.75, "ord1");
  renderer.addXTextLabel(1.75, "ord2");
  renderer.addXTextLabel(2.75, "ord3");
  renderer.addXTextLabel(3.75, "ord4");
  renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

  int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
  {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
      seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
  }

  final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(Result_BarActivity.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
  return grfv;

 /* ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);*/
 }

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{

 // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(colors[i]);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
  }


protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
{
 // sets lots of default values for this renderer

 renderer.setChartTitle(title);
 renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
 renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

 renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
 renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);

 renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
 renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

 renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
 renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

 renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
 renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
 }

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{
 // adds the axis titles and values into the data-set

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
int length = titles.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
   CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
   double[] v = values.get(i);
   int seriesLength = v.length;

   for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
   {
      series.add(v[k]);
    }
   dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
  }
  return dataset;
}}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1_invoke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:text="Invoke barchart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**result_barchart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic graph plot means keep sending data at particular time and `repaint` it

from other function send data to `value` list

```
int i = 0;
While(true)
{
  int[] series ={1,2,1,3,4,5,3,2,1,}  // ex: your input data to be ploted
  Thread.sleep(300000);  //aprox. 5minutes delay
  update(series[i]);
}
```

in `update()` function add data

```
update(int newval)
{
  value.add(newval);
 }
```

After this `repaint` the graph